# Pip, wheel and console_scripts

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I'm running into the following problem with python whl packages:

I have a package with a single entrypoint defined in my setup.py.
When I run `pip install .`, it installs the package *AND* the entry point wrapper properly.
When I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` followed by `pip install thing.whl`, it only install the package, but not the entrypoint.

How do I install the entrypoint properly from the created wheel package?

PS: When I unzip the wheel package, I do find "entrypoints.txt" with the expected entry. It just doesn't get installed in the environment bin.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem. The pip install method doesn't work?

Comment: I tried to improve the wording a bit. The `pip install .` works, but this requires a source distribution. Packaging it using wheel and installing the package doesn't work, because the entrypoint is not installed in the bin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wheels *used* to include pre-generated console script wrappers in the package, but this was sub-optimal and the files were removed. The installer is supposed to generate these wrapper scripts instead, but `pip` has not yet been updated to follow suit, see [issue 1067](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1067).

Until [pull request 1251](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1251) is part of a release, you'll have to use a separate command to install console scripts:

```
python -m wheel install-scripts thing.whl
```

See [*Setuptools scripts handling*](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#setuptools-scripts-handling) in the Wheel documentation.

The pull request was merged earlier this month (November 2014), and will be part of the [upcoming 6.0 release](https://github.com/pypa/pip/milestones). You could also use `pip` to upgrade itself to the development version from GitHub with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pypa/pip.git
```

Comment: If `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound` was raised instead, you may have to just run `python -m wheel install <pkg.whl>` and then `python -m wheel install-scripts pkg` afterwards, as the package may require something in itself for that script to work.